# zurb foundation center content in the grid

Tags: zurb-foundation, centering

I'm trying to center horizontally an image into a zurb column but it seems impossible. I tried everything, searched everywhere, but I cant get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns"><br />
        <img src="img_06.jpeg" alt="slide image">
    </div>
</div>
```

currently landscape images are alright on the 12 column grid, but when a portrait image comes along it is on the left side of the grid. If i give it a 25% padding it goest to the center, but I'm using php to pull all the images from a folder and generate the code on the fly, so i can't have 25% padding on all the images (landscape ones shrink).

Thanks

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Edit November 2015:** In Foundation 6 check out [Typography Helpers](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/typography-helpers.html)

---

**Edit April 2014:** In Foundation 5 check out [Utility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/utility-classes.html).

---

**Original answer:**

Use the text-center class.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns text-center"><br />
        <img src="img_06.jpeg" alt="slide image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Source: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/224

Comment: This answer is best since it uses an existing css style.  Creating a new class just adds bloat, wonk, meh and filler.  The question then floats into my mind about where the documentation is regarding this 'text-center' class.  Maybe I just missed it?

Comment: +1 this is the best answer because the OP asked about foundation and this solution uses a built-in foundation class.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was available before. Anyways, I've accepted this one as the correct answer.

Comment: Am I the only one frowning upon these utility classes? What's the difference with adding a `style="text-align: center"`?

Comment: @sroes There's no difference. If you are implying that this not semantic, you are correct. But then again most responsive frameworks isn't either.

Comment: For me there's a difference in these global utility classes and unsemantic classes that act as a modifier for some component (like `small-6` for the `grid` etc.). I still see using utility classes as a bad practice.

Comment: What a lifesaver. I didn't realize that I had to add the text-center to the parent div (since you can just add this style to any p-tag and it works). Now my buttons float right in the middle!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the centered class.

```
.five.columns.centered
```

Comment: I can't see the class definition. Do I miss something?

Comment: This doesn't work! THis centers grid element and not content itself - read here http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php

Answer (score 3):

Just add the class "text-center"

Answer (score 2):

Using foundation 4:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="wrap-img" class="large-12 columns"><br />
        <img src="img_06.jpeg" alt="slide image">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap-img img { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can get an image centered in Foundation 4 is to change to display:block; for img instead of display:inline-block;