# Making content inside the centered column as centered

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am new to Foundation.

I am trying to display tabs as list inside a centered column. However I am unable to align the list in the center.

Please guide me on this

My sample is at below
http://jsbin.com/natonopoqova/1/edit

Comment: Have you tried removing the float and set the `<li>`s to `display: inline-block` while setting the parent `<ul>` to `text-align: center;`?

Comment: See this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518615/centering-lists-in-zurb-foundation